# How can I post HTML element value to MySQL Database in Django using Ajax (Without using Form)

Tags: python, jquery, mysql, django, ajax

I am new to Django and currently facing a problem to post html tag data into database.

I have a "PICK CASE" button which on click should send the user_id (hidden html tag display:none) and case_id from the HTML Tags and send it to "pick_view" views and from there it should store the data in MySQL database.

For reference please find the image attached. [Case view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVUE8.png)

**tables.html**

```
<div class="containers pt-5 pb-3 px-4 py-4">
                  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token }}' /> 
                    <div class="d-none">
                      <p>User ID: </p><p class="user-id">{{id}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Case Number:</h3><h2 id="number"></h2>
                    <h4>Description:</h4>
                    <p class="mb-5" id="display"></p>
                    <div class="button d-inline-block" style="max-width: 50%;">
                      <button type="submit" id="pick" class=" pick-button btn btn-outline-primary border-radius-lg p-3">Pick Case</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-inline-block float-lg-end" style="max-width: 50%;">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger border-radius-lg p-3">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
<script>
$("#pick").click(function(){
        var user = $('.user-id').text();
        var ca = $('#number').text();
        ca = $.trim(ca);
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"{% url 'dashboard:pick_case' %}",
          data:{
            user_id:user,
            case_id:ca,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
          success:function(data){
            alert(data);
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

**Views.py**

```
def pick_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        case_id = request.POST.get('case_id')
        print(case_id)
        status = 2
        picked = Transaction()
        picked.Case_ID = case_id
        picked.Status = status
        picked.save()
        return HttpResponse("Case Picked Successfuly!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("POST ERROR")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard_view, name='dashboard_view'),
    path('tables', views.case_view, name='case_view'),
    path('tables', views.pick_view, name='pick_case'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Transaction(models.Model): ### Case Progress Table
    Case_ID = models.ForeignKey(CaseTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_Time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

After running the below code

```
success:function(data){
            alert(data);
          }
```

I get the following output:
[Output for the alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODD2F.png)
so apparently, I am not able to pass the values of "user" and "ca" in ajax.

Please Help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to see the error you are getting and what strategies you have tried to save the data to the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Kindly share full traceback of errors.

Comment: Hi @Chiperific,

Comment: @Chiperific, I have a "PICK CASE" button which on click takes the value of ".user_id" and "#number" and store it in a variable, i tried passing these values through ajax directing the URL to "pick_view" and through the view I am saving the data in MySQL database. The thing is I am not getting any error but the data is not being passed so i am confused where i have made the mistake is it while passing the values in ajax?

Comment: Hi @SunderamDubey, please refer the comment above.

Comment: @Chiperific, if you guys have to take the value from an HTML tag and store it in database what approach will you take?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use `JsonResponse` instead of `HTTPResponse`, it will be much more cleaner, easy to read and manipulate the returned data.

```
def pick_view(request):
    context={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            case_id = request.POST.get('case_id')
            print(case_id)
            status = 2
            picked = Transaction()
            picked.Case_ID = case_id
            picked.Status = status
            picked.save()
            context.update({'response':'Case Picked Successfuly!'})
        except Exception as e:
            context.update({'response':'POST ERROR : ' + str(e)})
    
    return JsonResponse(data=context)
```

Then in your ajax you can access the returned data using `alert(data.response);`

Also, please always use try except block when handling errors so it will not break your program during runtime.